# Hidden input messes with my padding

Tags: html, css

I have a `<li>` with 4 clickable buttons, I also have a border under it that shows when its clicked, I have also hidden a input in there for reasons, however its messing with my right padding, see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9qy53L32/

It looks as normal on "total" because I removed the hidden input there just to show, but on the others, when clicked, the border bottom stops right where the text does on the right side, so the padding is a bit messed up, can this be fixed?

Code:

```
<div class="holdLiftMenu">
   <ul class="holdLiftMenuUL">
      <li class="holdLiftMenuLI">
         <a class="holdLiftMenuA total current">Total
            <input type="hidden" name="hid4" id="hid4" value="4" />
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="holdLiftMenuLI">
         <a class="holdLiftMenuA squat">Squat
            <input type="hidden" name="hid1" id="hid1" value="" />
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="holdLiftMenuLI">
         <a class="holdLiftMenuA benchpress">Benchpress
            <input type="hidden" name="hid2" id="hid2" value="" />
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="holdLiftMenuLI">
         <a class="holdLiftMenuA deadlift">Deadlift
            <input type="hidden" name="hid3" id="hid3" value="" />
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.holdLiftMenu li a').on('click', function () {
        $('li a.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.holdLiftMenu {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}

.holdLiftMenuUL {
    margin:0;
}

.holdLiftMenuLI {
    display:inline-block;
}

.holdLiftMenuA {
    background-color:white;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color: black;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align:center;    
}

.current {
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
```

Comment: If I remove the whitespace so it's like <a ...>blah<input ... /></a> in your jsfiddle then it seems to work ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from my comment, if you add white-space: nowrap; should fix it

```
.holdLiftMenuA {
    background-color:white;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color: black;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align:center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: awesome! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

I tried a different approach using your code (see demo).

Hope this helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul li a').on('click', function() {
    $('li a.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
  });
});
```

```css
div ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

div ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

div ul li input {
  display: none;
}

.current {
 border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Total</a>
     <input type="text">
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Squat</a>
     <input type="text">
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Benchpress</a>
     <input type="text">
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Deadlift</a>
     <input type="text">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```